# Where can I find the jars folder in Spark 1.6?

Tags: apache-spark, jar, apache-spark-1.6

From the [Spark downloads page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), if I download the [tar file for v2.0.1](http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz), I see that it contains some jars that I find useful to include in my app.

If I download the [tar file for v1.6.2](http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz) instead, I don't find the jars folder in there. Is there an alternate package type I should use from that site? I am currently choosing the default (pre-built for Hadoop 2.6). Alternately, where I can find those Spark jars - should I get each of them individually from http://spark-packages.org?

Here is an indicative bunch of jars I want to use:

- hadoop-common
- spark-core
- spark-csv
- spark-sql
- univocity-parsers
- spark-catalyst
- json4s-core

Comment: Before Spark 2, by default, there is just one monster of a `spark-assembly*.jar` under `$SPARK_HOME/lib` that contains all the dependencies. If you want the individual JARs you must recompile Spark. Have fun!

Comment: Also `spark-csv` is a separate download *(was not embedded in Spark code base before V2)* and requires Apache `commons-csv`.

Comment: Thanks! Care to add this as an answer so that I can close this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way Sparks ships its run-time has changed from V1 to V2.

- In V2, by default, you have **multiple** JARs under
  `$SPARK_HOME/jars`
- In V1, by default, there was just **one**
  massive `spark-assembly*.jar` under `$SPARK_HOME/lib` that
  contains all the dependencies.

I believe you can change the default behavior, but that would require recompiling Spark on your own...

And also, about `spark-csv` specifically:

- In V2, the CSV file format is natively supported by SparkSQL
- In V1, you have to download `spark-csv` (for Scala 2.10) from [Spark-Packages.org](https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-csv) plus `commons-csv` from [Commons.Apache.org](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv) and add both JARs to your CLASSPATH
  (with `--jars` on command line, or with prop `spark.driver.extraClassPath` + instruction `sc.addJar()` if the command line does not work for some reason)
  ...and the syntax is more cumbersome, too

---

Excerpt from the vanilla `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-class` as of Spark 2.1.x (greatly simplified)

> *# Find Spark **jars***

```
  SPARK_JARS_DIR="${SPARK_HOME}/jars"
  LAUNCH_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_JARS_DIR/*"
```

And as of Spark 1.6.x

> *# Find **assembly jar***

```
  ASSEMBLY_DIR="${SPARK_HOME}/lib"
  ASSEMBLY_JARS="$(ls -1 "$ASSEMBLY_DIR" | grep "^spark-assembly.*hadoop.*\.jar$" || true)"
  SPARK_ASSEMBLY_JAR="${ASSEMBLY_DIR}/${ASSEMBLY_JARS}"
  LAUNCH_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_ASSEMBLY_JAR"
```

Comment: in spark 2.2.0 dropping the jars in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` seems to make the jars available to `spark-shell`  and `pyspark` via terminal, however when I submit a spark app those jars are not picked up, i get ClassNotFound excpt, do I need to specify anything else when building my spark context?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"submit a spark app"_ >> does that imply `spark-submit` shell that invokes `spark-class` among many other things? Otherwise, you'll have to reverse-engineer the whole mess - good luck with that.

Comment: In case someone gets here from Google searching the `jars` folder in AWS EMR, in spark 2.x it is in `/usr/lib/spark/jars/`. Check [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-permanently-install-library/) from AWS to see more info.